# Is it possible to limit display of products in the catalog on a per template basis in Brilliant Retail?

Tags: channel-entries, variable, parameters, brilliantretail

In BR's settings, it is possible to limit the number of products displayed in the catalog and paginate the results. However, that seems to set the limit for any and all catalogs referenced throughout the site.

What I'm looking for is a way to limit it per template; for example on the main page, it is a separate template from the 'products' page, and a separate 'catalog'. I want to change the product results shown on the main page to something small, say, four products, while still allowing the products shown on the "products" page, to stay at the default setting of $N.

I looked through the BR docs and 'limit' does not seem to be an optional template variable or parameter. I've tried setting it by using {exp:channel:entries channel="channel-name" limit="4"} but no matter where I place it in the template, it just shows the default product count, set at 8, four times over.

I tried the same without the {exp:brilliant_retail:catalog} code and it displayed nothing, even though I was specifying the url_title. I also tried by category ID, I presume I have that info by hovering over the edit link in the BR category settings, I'm not entirely sure. But that did not work either.

Is there a way to do what I'm seeking to do? Maybe I'm just missing something obvious? Thanks.

Comment: I concur that from the docs it looks like pagination is strictly global in BrillientRetail. Does BrillientRetail store its products in a channel? If so you should be able to list them all (and use the built in channel entries pager) with `exp:channel:entries channel="???" dynamic="no"` however I'm not sure if this is how products are handled with BrilleientRetail. Did you ask on their supporrt forums? with such a price tag I'm ure they'll offer some assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BrilliantRetail catalog tag does not currently allow for changing the number of results to pagination per template. For your use case though I would consider a relationship or using the BR product fieldtype to pull specific products on the main page. We generally setup a home page channel for our clients and allow them to select a few 'featured' products for the home page that way.

Comment: I started by using the default templates provided with BR, which has the front page showing a list of items specified by a category, using "url_title" to call them. I will look into seeing how to configure it to use "Featured" instead. Thanks.